# Google Webmaster Not indexing Complete Sitemap

Tags: sitemap, google-search-console

Google webmaster is not indexing my URLs don't know for what reasons. It says that 121 URLs are submitted but only 45 are indexed from past 2 weeks. Following is the URL of my sitemap
https://insta-care.net/home/SitemapXml

Can you please guide me if something is wrong with my sitemap?